# Are log-linear models exponential models?

Tags: distributions, terminology, exponential-family, log-linear

What is usually referred to as "log-linear models"? Is a log-linear model an exponential model where the normalization constant is 1 (since its logarithm needs to be a linear function)? Or is there very little difference between the use of the two terms, and they are in fact interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say what is "usually referred to" without more context, as terminology is not well standardized across fields.

In the most common statistical context, I would say "[log-linear model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis)" refers to a Poisson GLM that is applied to a multi-way contingency table and presented in a special form.  This is the way Agresti uses the term in his *Categorical Data Anaysis*, for example ([Google book search](https://books.google.com/books?id=6PHHE1Cr44AC&pg=PT383&dq=agresti+categorical+data+analysis+CHAPTER+9&hl=en&sa=X&ei=k-RsVereNIevsAXA3ICADw&ved=0CEAQuwUwAg#v=onepage&q=agresti%20categorical%20data%20analysis%20CHAPTER%209&f=false)).  I have an R-based example of using a log-linear model here: [$χ^2$ of multidimensional data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148174/7290).

Answer (score -1):

They are different, but it's a bit ambiguous without extra context.

Log-linear models usually refer to an OLS linear model with logged response, or sometimes a GLM with a Normal family, log link function. The Normal distribution is in the exponential family.

If you actually have an exponential response,  you would use a GLM with Gamma family, but this typically uses the inverse link, not a log. Also in the exponential family.